# SUMIF when cells do not contain "text a" OR "text b" (LibreOffice-Calc)

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I've got a spreadsheet of purchase information that has the following format:

| Account | Category | Withdraw | Deposit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CC | Home | 21.22 |  |
| Checking | Payment | 21.22 |  |
| CC | Payment |  | 21.22 |
| CC | Transit | 50.00 |  |
| Checking | Income |  | 5000 |
| CC | Food | 31.49 |  |
| CC | Hobbies | 15.00 |  |
| Checking | Transfer | 3000 |  |
| Savings | Transfer |  | 3000 |

I want to sum all values in the Withdraw column that do **not** have the category "Payment" **or** "Transfer" in the same row.

I can get one or the other with something like `=SUMIF(B:B,"<>Payment",C:C)`, but I can't figure out how to exclude both.

`=SUMIF(B:B,"<>Payment"&"<>Transfer",C:C)` doesn't give me the correct value, and `=SUMIF(B:B,AND("<>Payment","<>Transfer"),C:C)` gives me an error.

I feel like there's an operator combination for this that I just haven't been able to find?

Comment: [Sumifs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) (plural)!? .. Allows multiple criteria

Comment: @xerx593 `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"<>Payment",B:B,"<>Transfer")` is giving me Err:502 for some reason.

Comment: @xerx593 Aw pebkac, had a typo. Correcting it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely missed that SUMIFS existed, as @xerx593 pointed out. `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"<>Payment",B:B,"<>Transfer")` gives the results I was looking for.